# How Do You List Unique Values and Group Them

Tags: r

I am trying to list out the unique values that correspond to a group in another column. In this case, I am trying to list out all of the unique election districts that correspond to each county in my state. How do you group unique values by a category in another column?

For reference, this is my code:

```
## Trying unique function ##

unique(SoS_Voterfile_101723$ED) %>%
  group_by(SoS_Voterfile_101723$county)

## Yield error: "Error in UseMethod("group_by") :

no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object 
  of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Is there a way to do this other than just doing counts?

Answer (score 0):

First you group by county, then you list the unique values of ED per county. Also, when we use the pipe operator we dont need to reference the data in the further actions.

Try this peace of code my friend:

```
SoS_Voterfile_101723 %>%
      group_by(county) %>%
      summarize(unique_ED = list(unique(ED)))
```

This code will store the unique values in a new column called unique_ED and print it on the console. If you want to save this output in your enviroment use the assignment operator `<-`

```
my_new_object <- SoS_Voterfile_101723 %>%
      group_by(county) %>%
      summarize(unique_ED = list(unique(ED)))
```

Comment: Sir/Madame you are a hero and a scholar :D

Comment: I did have one last question. How do you show all of the values? I noticed that the ones with a lot of the larger counties have a [...] at the end indicating that there are a lot of values there. How would I view all of them? Is there a way to sort the values displayed numerically?